# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UILabel?' and 'String'

Tags: swift, xcode5

Error : Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UILabel?' and 'String'

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let Soft = 5
  let Medium = 8
    let Hard = 12


    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let hardness = sender.titleLabel

        if hardness == "Soft"{
            print(Soft)
        }
        else if hardness == "Medium"{
            print (Medium)
        }
        else {
            print (Hard)
        }

    }


}
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: What do you think that error is trying to tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give the line number the error is on, but looking at the text it mentions operation `==` so I'm guessing it's one of these:

```swift
if hardness == "Soft"{

else if hardness == "Medium"{
```

"Soft" and "Medium" are the strings, so hardness must be a `'UILabel?`.  Those types can't be compared to each other.  You must want the text displayed on the button?  Looking at the [UILabel docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel), there is a `text` property so you probably want to change this line to grab the string representing the button's text:

```swift
let hardness = sender.titleLabel.text
```

Are you using dynamic buttons?  It would be less error prone to just compare the sender with the button your are checking for.  Comparing hard-coded strings to the text of the button can lead to run-time errors.  Maybe you didn't get the case right, misspelled the text, or decided to localize later so the text may be different in a different language.   These errors wouldn't be caught at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

[UIButton.titleLabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel) is a `UILabel` and it stores its text in [`UILabel.text`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620538-text) property:

```
let hardness = sender.titleLabel.text
```

In the case of `UIButton` you can also access [`UIButton.currentTitle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624032-currenttitle) property:

```
let hardness = sender.currentTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare two different types. To get the actual text of UILabel, you'll need `hardness.text`.

Answer (score 1):

An `UIButton` exposes its label through an `UILabel` that manage the drawing of its text. Thus change:

```
let hardness = sender.titleLabel
```

to

```
let hardness = sender.titleLabel.text
```

`UIKit` docs says:

> **UIButton**
>
> `var titleLabel: UILabel?`
>
> > A view that displays the value of the currentTitle property for a button.

and:

> **UILabel**
>
> `var text: String?`
>
> > The current text that is displayed by the label.

There is also a more direct way using the `currentTitle`:

> **UIButton**
>
> var currentTitle: String?
>
> > The current title that is displayed on the button.

Thus:

```
let hardness = sender.currentTitle
```

will also work.